# Flex4 Anchor Points

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I created one aplication that have a lot of components and a height of 2500 ,in the bottom I have a navigation menu.

I need to take the focus to the top of the page after a click in the bottom.

How can this be done?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the verticalScrollPosition to 0, i haven't try it, but it logically works. haha